# Git keeps mentioning my old username even if I can't find a trace of it

Tags: git, github

`remote: Permission to MYUSERNAME/project.git denied to OLD-USER-NAME`

I have 2 GitHub users. One for personal use and one for work use. MYUSERNAME will be my personal one for this example and OLD-USER-NAME the work one.
I've stopped using OLD-USER-NAME a while ago but I'm getting the above error when trying to push to a github https. I solved the problem by pushing directly to https://MYUSERNAME@github.com...

I'm trying to figure out why my OLD-USER-NAME was even mentioned and how git "knows about it".

Things I've tried:

1. `ssh-add -l` -> `The agent has no identities.`
2. I couldn't find any .ssh folder.
3. I don't have any ssh keys on both of my github accounts
4. `git config --global --edit` or `git config --edit` shows MYUSERNAME
5. `git remote --verbose` which gave me: `origin    https://github.com/MYUSERNAME/project.git (fetch) origin https://github.com/MYUSERNAME/project.git (push)`
6. OLD-USER-NAME GitHub -> Settings -> Security History I can see my ip with a green dot next to it. Maybe it got something to do with it?

Comment: What happens if you `cd` to the `.git` folder of the repository and run `grep -r OLD-USER-NAME .`? If that shows nothing, you can pretty much rule out anything on the local system.

Comment: @DavidZ Great idea. I got no results. For `MYUSERNAME` I get a lot of results. If local system is out what else is there?

Comment: Actually you can also run the same `grep` command from within your home directory if you have time to wait around for it. That way it'll catch things like `~/.gitconfig`, `~/.ssh/config`, and so on. (So I was wrong to say that running it from the repository git directory eliminates anything on the local system.) Of course I see that you have already checked those, but just in case...

Comment: @DavidZ Just did that. No results. Weird. Any point on doing it on all the drive and not just the home directory?

Comment: I doubt it. I mean, if you want to assure yourself, and you have a lot of time, and you're not worried about overstressing the drive (probably not a big deal unless you have an old drive), then it couldn't hurt. But I would be very surprised if something outside your home directory is responsible for this. Already the behavior you're seeing is quite odd. Personally I would run `strace -e trace=file git ...` to see which files the command accesses and then focus on those, although I would do so with the understanding that it's unlikely to give the solution.

Comment: Or it might be time to contact github support.

Comment: @DavidZ There's a good chance I'll do that if I wont find a solution. Would you mind pasting your comments into an answer? Although it didn't solve my problem there's some great info here.

Comment: Well, all I've posted is ways to get diagnostic information, it doesn't really constitute an answer. So I don't think it should be posted as one. (That being said, if you'd like to make my comments into an answer and post it yourself, that's definitely allowed.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to everything mentioned in the question and @gturri suggestions in the comments, the next step is to check whether git or the os are caching your credentials.

Check the keyring on your OSX / Linux / cygwin and also check if `git config [--global] credential.helper` has been set.

Comment: Great advice. The git command returned `error: key does not contain a section: [--global]` but I did find my old username in my keychain under github.com. Does git command line can access that? I had no idea. I'll report back if that was the problem.

Comment: The brackets just indicate that the argument is optional. Try `git config --global credential.helper`. In any case, if you remove your old user from the keychain, git won't be able to find it.

Comment: Nothing happens. After taking a second look on my keychain, the github accounts are listed under `kind: Internet password` so I don't think that's it.

Comment: Third look a charm. After I took another look in my keychain I noticed that the github item gave access to something called git-credential-osxkeychain so I'm guessing that keychain entry was in did the problem.. I'll know for sure after I'll push something.

Answer (score 7):

you should check your remote:

```
git remote --verbose
```

If it says

```
origin  git@github.com:OLD-USER-NAME/project.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:OLD-USER-NAME/project.git (push)
```

then your can fix it doing

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:MYUSERNAME/project.git
```

Comment: it says `origin https://github.com/MYUSERNAME/project.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/MYUSERNAME/project.git (push)`

Comment: Then it wasn't the correct guess... Another attempt: try the ssh url rather than the https one, ie `git@github.com:user/project.git` rather then `https://github.com/user/project.git`. I'm not totally convinced, but I often had less issues with this url

Comment: I'll try it on my next push. I'm just very curious from where git fetches the `OLD-USER-NAME` string. I couldn't find it anywhere on my system.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue as the OP, and I'm not sure if he reported back, but the OSX keychain entry was my problem.  After removing it, git push would prompt me for my user name and password.

Comment: That was in did the problem. Forgot to accept the right answer above.

Answer (score 0):

So, I ran `env GIT_TRACE_CURL=true git clone https://github.com/user/private-repo-path` and found that it was sending an old username.

Then I tried all the different options in here. Finally, after researching I figured the issue was that old user and password were saved in .netrc file on my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

git remote set-url origin "https://new_username@github.com/new_username/github-repository-name.git"
It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this by deleting ssh key from my old account.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted ssh key, checked keychain, but nothing worked. Then came across one of the below ans, but it has password authentication based approach. Since password authentication is deprecated, you can do this (You need to ensure that you have your public ssh key saved in your github account):

```
git remote set-url origin "git@github.com:<username>/<repository>.git"
```